# When yield array with Promise.reject, I got success response

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm following promise generators from [here](https://www.promisejs.org/generators/)

Please follow below code

```
function async(makeGenerator){
  return function () {
    var generator = makeGenerator.apply(this, arguments);

    function handle(result){
      // result => { done: [Boolean], value: [Object] }
      if (result.done) return Promise.resolve(result.value);

      return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(function (res){
        return handle(generator.next(res));
      }, function (err){
        return handle(generator.throw(err));
      });
    }

    try {
      return handle(generator.next());
    } catch (ex) {
      return Promise.reject(ex);
    }
  }
}

async(function*(){
  yield [Promise.reject('Promise error')]
})()
.then(function(){
  console.log('success')
})
.catch(function(data){
 console.log('error',data)
})
```

Its output is `success`, Instead of `error`

If I do `yield Promise.reject('Promise error')` then `.catch` is called as expected.

What I need to do, so I can catch Promise rejection with

`yield [Promise.reject('Promise error')]`

Comment: You've yielded an array, the contents of the array are not inspected, and an array just counts as a normal value. What is your actual objective? Why not yield a rejected promise, e.g. `yield Promise.reject(['Promise error'])` if you want the error to be an array?

Comment: I want to do some operations like `yield [saveUserData(),saveOtherData(),doSomethingUsefull()]` and get output of all in one array

Comment: One option would be `yield Promise.all([saveUserData(),saveOtherData(),doSomethingUsefull()])`?

Comment: Cool!!, will give a try on this.

Comment: Also you'd be better off just using [`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co), there is no reason to write this function yourself.

Comment: Yep, that will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @loganfsmyth

We can modify the code from

```
yield [Promise.reject('Promise error')]
```

to

```
yield Promise.all([Promise.reject('Promise error')]);
```

Will give expected result.